# What is the meaning of using -pthread when compiling in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

When we're using the library pthread in C, when we compile code using GCC we have to specifify: `gcc test.c -o test -pthread`. What is that and why do we need to use this (and why other libraries don't require this)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is that and why do we need to use this (and why other libraries don't require this)?

it depends if you want to use threading in test.c. It is not mandatory (i.e. you don't "have to" specify, it depends on your application)

`pthread` is a flag. More about `pthread` from gcc man page:

> -pthread Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.
> It does not affect the thread safety of object code produced by the
> compiler or that of libraries supplied with it.

Comment: The entry is from https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc. another reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html. thanks

Comment: Oh I see, `-pthread` is listed repeatedly for each target architecture that supports it.  That entry is apparently for IA-64.

Comment: i see, i think it is fair to remove the last line

Comment: Its entry in the the actual gcc manual is in the middle of: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: Thank you all for the answer!